# How to create delay in rotation or smooth rotation in firemonkey camera

Tags: 3d, firemonkey

Using Firemonkey My Camera is attached to TDummy and I want to rotate this TDummy on my y-axis. It's possible but it jumps directly to 270 degrees and don't know how to rotate it smoothly. here is simple code:

```
procedure TfrmMain.plngoleftClick(Sender: TObject);
begin

 Dummy2.RotationAngle.Y :=270;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution is

```
Dummy2.AnimateFloat('RotationAngle.Y',Dummy2.RotationAngle.Y-90,0.8,TAnimationType.Out,TInterpolationType.Linear);
```